# Process throwing "Unexpected return" error

Tags: ruby, bash, chef-infra

I am trying to create a `Chef` recipe that will read attributes from a `Role`, and one of those attributes will contain `Bash` code that needs to be executed on the server.

Hence, I created the below process:

```
def proc_test(command)
  proc = Proc.new { |command| command_out = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(command) ; command_out.run_command ; return command_out.stdout + command_out.stderr  }
  proc.call(command)
end
```

which, when run like this:

```
node.set['attributes']['nested_attribute'] = proc_test("hostname")
```

works. But if I attempt to do this:

```
command="hostname"
node.set['attributes']['nested_attribute'] = proc_test(command)
```

it throws this error:

```
LocalJumpError
--------------
unexpected return
```

Can someone help me with this?

If, instead of using the `return` keyword, I use `put`, I get the same error.

Comment: Putting all of that Proc code on one line is pointless and severely impairs readability. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @tadman No one  besides me will see this code. So it was not so important.

Comment: Guess what, we're looking at your code right now. It's important.

Comment: @tadman Yes. You are right. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `return` can't be called from `Ruby` procs. Just skip `return` to avoid the error:

```
 def proc_test(command)
     proc = Proc.new do |command|
       command_out = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(command) 
       command_out.run_command
       command_out.stdout + command_out.stderr
     end

     proc.call(command)
 end
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked like charm. One question, If I attempt to run a command that does not exist on the server ( for instance "finger" where finger is not available ), it also throws me an error about "Local Jump: Unexpected return". How can I catch that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you think you need a Proc at all. Just use the normal `shell_out!` helper method or a `bash` resource.

Comment: How do I do that? I dont mind using Processes. Its simply that when I attempted to use it directly on the code, it failed too.

Comment: Yes. Anyway, Igor response works perfectly. Only problem now, is that I get that exception if the command that I send to the process does not exist on the server. For instance this "proc_test(command)" will work perfectly if command equals "pwd" but it will throw an exception if command equals "blahblahblah". I was expecting to get the Unix error stream, "Command not found" or something similar, not having Ruby to throw an exception. :(

Comment: We should probably take this to Slack, whatever you're trying to do is probably a bad idea.